# Looking for the best scroll-view solution

Tags: ios, swift

I want to learn and implement the most suitable/simple solution to display dynamic data (JSON) in three lines and an active (clickable) download icon. Screenshot is attached

I would be glad to get your ideas and advice!
Thanks

[image: Scroll view design]

Comment: As Visal said below (+1), `UITableView` is the way to go for simple UIKit implementation. It actually _is_ a scroll view (i.e., it is a subclass of `UIScrollView`), but is ideally suited for scrollable, repeating cells of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView` is the way to go, as you can reuse a custom cell you define. And to add to that, `UITableView`'s cells are loaded lazily and are reused. You can use a `UIScrollView` but if you have a lot of rows it can horde your memory real fast. In your case, a `UIScrollView` can be used as well, but if you plan on expanding, `UITableViews` would be the choice. All in all, go with a `UITableView` + a custom `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Thank you so much! I have it done and it works perfectly with a looooooot of rows! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have array of data like this, the best way is using `UITableView` class. With `UITableview`, you can custom your `UITableViewCell` on the fly